# Google Cloud publishing from Visual Studio: Publish menu item is disabled

Tags: visual-studio, google-cloud-platform, visual-studio-2017

I need to publish some projects which now is in Microsoft Azure to Google Cloud platform.

I produced all necessary steps from documentation https://cloud.google.com/tools/visual-studio/docs/quickstart : created a VM with Windows instance and required settings, also defined the credentials in Google Cloud Explorer in Visual Studio

But unfortunately the "Publish to Google Cloud" menu item is disabled.

Could I have any suggestions how should I solve that?

[image: Visual Studio popup menu]

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if the issue is still relevant. You need to setup billing and then add the account details in your Visual Studio (Tools > Google